# Using getSegment

Tags: navigation, getsegment

Can anyone shed any light on why the following doesn't work for `getSegment(2)` but the previous does for `getSegment(1)`?

URL structure for these two examples are:

`root.com/blog`

`root.com/blog/trends`

```
 <a class="button button--outline-blue {% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == 'blog' %}current{% endif %}" href="/blog">All</a>

{% nav category in craft.categories.group('blogCategories') %}

    <a class="button button--outline-blue {% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == 'trends' %}current{% endif %}" href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>

{% endnav %}
```

Comment: What do you see if you you `{{ dump(craft.request.getSegment(2)) }}` on the  `/blog/trends` page?  Any chance the result you are seeing has to do with CSS styles?  I expect when you say it doesn't work you mean the `current` class is not being added to the a tag in the second example.

Comment: Urgh ignore that question it is working I was just using the wrong template! *Face Palm*

I do have a follow up question on how to make what I've used in the example as 'trends' to be the category title? I've tried what's been updated in the question.

Comment: Can you add an official answer to your original question and post your follow-up as a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code above is fine. I was stupidly updating the wrong template